# spark csv writer - escape string without using quotes

Tags: csv, apache-spark

I am trying to escape delimiter character that appears inside data. Is there a way to do it by passing option parameters? I can do it from udf, but I am hoping it is possible using options.

```
val df = Seq((8, "test,me\nand your", "other")).toDF("number", "test", "t")
df.coalesce(1).write.mode("overwrite").format("csv").option("quote", "\u0000").option("delimiter", ",").option("escape", "\\").save("testcsv1")
```

But the escape is not working. The output file is written as

```
8,test,me
and your,other
```

I want the output file to be written as.

```
8,test\,me\\nand your,other
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain, but I think if you had your sequence as

```
Seq((8, "test\\,me\\\\nand your", "other"))
```

and did not specify a custom escape character, it would behave as you are expecting and give you `8,test\,me\\nand your,other` as the output. This is because `\\` acts simply as the character '\' rather than an escape, so they are printed where you want and the n immediately after is not interpreted as part of a newline character.